# TYPO3: How to render images with absolute path in Ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, image, typo3

When I generate an image in a TYPO3 11 extension which is not based on Extbase/Fluid, then this is accomplished by a call (tt_products):

```
$imageCode = $cObj->getContentObject($contentObject)->render($imageConf);
```

This will result in a HTML code:

```
<img src="/fileadmin/_processed_/6/8/image__aaa05df7b9.gif" width="171" height="100" alt="" border="0">
```

However when I use an Ajax call with the same method, then the returned code is without an absolute path starting with "/":

```
<img src="fileadmin/_processed_/6/8/image__aaa05df7b9.gif" width="171" height="100" alt="" border="0">
```

Therefore no image will be found under the following link of a current page "http://example.com/mypage/mysubpage"!

**The file http://example.com/mypage/mysubpage/fileadmin/_processed_/6/8/image__aaa05df7b9.gif does not exist**

The image is not there but here:

```
 http://example.com/fileadmin/_processed_/6/8/image__aaa05df7b9.gif
```

What is missing on the Ajax side?

The **image** setup is taken from [tt_products setup.txt](https://github.com/franzholz/tt_products/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/PluginSetup/Main/setup.txt)

A feature "forceAbsoluteUrl = 1" is needed.

See [Feature: #64286](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/9.5/en-us/Changelog/7.6/Feature-64286-AddedAbsoluteUrlOptionToUriimageAndImageViewHelper.html)

Comment: You are yelling for a feature which is still implemented in TYPO3 core for an extension you maintain? I don't get your question. Also, you don't use this feature obviously in your TypoScript file.

Comment: The feature of IMAGE rendering is part of TYPO3. However I cannot use the feature "forceAbsoluteUrl" if I cannot find it to be available for IMAGE rendering in the TYPO3 Docu.  And it is not about Extbase/Fluid.

Comment: You mean you need the absolute URL in IMAGE object? Then create a feature request on forge.typo3.org. Here you won't get a feature.

Comment: What code is for your AJAX request? Do you use eID or a page type? Is there a TypoScript loading beside your IMAGE configuration? What about `config.absRefPrefix = /`?

Comment: This has formerly been a Ajax call with eID. But since TYPO3 10 this had to be reprogrammed based on a Middleware in the extension taxajax. Now it works with the setup `page.config.absRefPrefix = /` .
The normal Frontend already had the correct url `/fileadmin/...` . Only the images from the Ajax call had relative paths which cannot work with the routing API and the speaking url. 
This can be no feature request either, because it did work automatically in all TYPO3 versions before 11.